Есть ли какой-то магический метод который вызывается когда класс расширяется дочерним?
class Parent:
     
    @classmethod
    def __extends__(cls, child_cls):
        pass
    
# trigger __extends__ method
class Child(Parent): pass


Всё, что относится к поведению классов, в питоне делается через метаклассы. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756793/8324991

Yes
class Parent:
  def __init_subclass__(child_cls):
    # do magic with child_cls
    return

# this call __init_subclass__ parent method
class Child(Parent): 
  pass




пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
